# Viewing cached data with GeoWebCache?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geowebcache

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.42, 53.50], 6);

var wmts = L.tileLayer('C:/Program Files(x86)/GeoServer 2.15.1/data_dir/gwc/web/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    wmts: true,
});
wmts.addTo(map);
```

The data I cache with geowebcache is stored C:/Program Files(x86)/GeoServer 2.15.1/data_dir/gwc/web/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.
How can I view this cached data with Leaflet my file formats image or png.

[image]

Comment: I edited the question and removed reference to OpenLayers, since otherwise it could be closed as "needing more focus".

Comment: https://github.com/kcl-ddh/leaflet-geowebcache-plugin/blob/master/src/Leaflet_GWC_Layer.js

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use  browser to view files on file system on your local machine, then for security reasons you cannot refer to those files by absolute path, you have to use relative path.

In your case that would mean that you have to put for example `myTileViewer.html` file with your code somewhere on the path to tiles, let's say in the folder `C:/Program Files(x86)/GeoServer 2.15.1/data_dir`, and then your code could look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.42, 53.50], 6);

var wmts = L.tileLayer('gwc/web/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    wmts: true,
});
wmts.addTo(map);
```